# Order of cache items after update mutation using Apollo Client

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have a question concerning Apollo Client's behaviour when dispatching an update mutation.

I have a little application that fetches data and allows you to modify it. After the modification, an update mutation is sent to graphQL. The changes can be seen instantly on the UI since the update of a single item triggers an automatic cache update by Apollo.

However, I noticed that when I refresh the page after an update, the order of the items I previously fetched is changed with the recently updated item going at the end of the list.

I was just wondering if this is the normal behaviour to expect and if there was a way to force the cache to keep the same order after an update?

Edit: Here's the code for my resolver, mutation and useMutation call.

Resolver:

```
async UpdateUser(parent, args, ctx, info) {
            const { id, input } = args;
            const updatedUser = await ctx.prisma.user.update({
                where: {
                    id,
                },
                data: {
                    ...input,
                },
            });
            return updatedUser;
        }
```

Mutation:

```
export const UPDATE_USER_MUTATION = gql`
    mutation UpdateUser($id: String, $input: CreateUserInput) {
        UpdateUser(id: $id, input: $input) {
            id
            name
            email
        }
    }
`;
```

useMutation:

```
        UpdateField({
            variables: {
                id: data.fieldID,
                input: {
                    [data.fieldName]: value,
                },
            },
        });
```

Edit 2: Here's a gif what's going on..
[image: App behaviour]

Thank you!

Comment: code? change update to follow api order

Comment: I will edit my post to include the code for the mutation. I thought about changing the update, but I can't figure out how to make it follow the api order. Dziekuje!

Comment: Added the code, hope it makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Mutation `update` option can update (or insert) properly list/array (query cached result) following BE sorting ...

... but it will fail on longer datasets, paginated results - on list query refetch record can be removed from current [page] list/array. It will be more confusing behavior.

**IMHO fighting is not worth the effort, it's already acceptable behavior (mutation of indexed/ordering field).**

### Possible solutions:

- don't refetch list query, only update the query list cache (mutation `update` - it will update the list view);
- for small datasets, use FE sortable table component (BE order doesn't matter).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I guess maybe I would just use BE sorting when it would be related to immutable data and let the FE do the sorting when it comes to user related data. One question though, where should the sorting be done? I guess both when the data is initially fetched but also on the TypePolicies option in the cache configuration right?